# How to Concatenate Unicode string into a character string to pass into mysql call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mariadb, wxwidgets

I am trying to concatenate an array of strings into a character array - but one of the strings is in a foreign language (why I need UTF8).  I can see the UTF8 string in their appropriate language in the debugger (Visual Studio) after I read it from the database and put it into the wxString array, but when I try to concatenate the string to the array, t never gets put in there.

I have tried variable.mb_str()
              variable.mb.str().data(). Neither seems to work in the strcat
for my Language data. The other data is concatenated fine. All of the data comes from a MariaDB database call.

```
 int i, numRows;
 wxString query;
 wxString sortby;
 wxString group_list;
 wxString *stringGroups;
 char holdString[400];

 /*   Try UTF Force */
 query.Printf(_("set names 'utf8'"));
 mysql_query(mDb, query.mb_str());
 result = mysql_store_result(mDb);
 mysql_free_result(result);
 query.Printf(_("select GROUP_NAME from USER_PERMS where USER_NAME = 
    \"%s\" 
 ORDER BY GROUP_NAME "),  riv_getuser().c_str() );
 mysql_query(mDb, query.mb_str());   
 result = mysql_store_result(mDb);
 numRows = mysql_num_rows(result);
 stringGroups = new wxString[numRows + 1];
 i = 0; 
 while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))      
 {        
    stringGroups[i] = wxString(row[0], wxConvUTF8);
    i++;
 }
 mysql_free_result(result);
 i = 0;
 strcpy (holdString,"IN (\'");
 while (i < numRows)
 {
   if (i != 0) strcat(holdString, "\', \'");
   strcat(holdString, (const char *)stringGroups[i].mb_str().data());
   i++;  
 }   
 strcat (holdString," \')");

-- END OF CODE --

--ACTUAL stringGroup that fails -- Debugger Watch Output
stringGroups[2] {m_impl=L"文字化け"...
```

I expect to get:

```
IN ( 'test' , 'test' , '文字化け' )
```

what I get

```
IN ( 'test','test2','' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `strcpy()` and `strcat()` with `wxString`, this is just needlessly error-prone. If you use `wxString` in the first place, build the entire string you need and then `utf8_str()` method to get the buffer containing UTF-8 string contents which you can then pass to whatever function you need.

Do keep in mind that this buffer is temporary, so you can't rely on it continuing to exist if you don't make a copy of it or at least extend its lifetime, i.e.

```
auto const& buf = some_wx_string.utf8_str();
... now you can use buf.data() safely until the end of scope ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To get UTF8 from `wxString` you need to call `ToUTF8()`. Similarly, for getting UTF8 into `wxString` there is `FromUTF8()`. Both are members of `wxString` and documented.

Answer (score 1):

`wxString::mb_str()` converts to a multi-byte string in your current locale. Presumably the characters in your string aren't representable in your locale so the conversion fails and an empty string is returned.

You should pass `wxConvUTF8` as a parameter or simply call `utf8_str` or `ToUTF8` instead.